# Average number of days to reach hell?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, puzzle

I came across a puzzle over the internet(https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/gates-of-heaven/).

> Amanda dies and reaches at the gate of heaven.
>
> She has three doors in front of her out of which only one of them leads to heaven.
>
> Out of the other two gates, one leads to hell for one day and then back to the gate and one leads to hell for two days and then back to the gate.
>
> If she chooses one of these two gates, the gates are shuffled when she returns back.
>
> How long is Amanda expected to take to reach heaven?

Surprisingly its answer is 3 days. There are certain verbal solutions over the internet but I couldn't reach its mathematical proof. Can anyone help?

Comment: This is a fairly straightforward exercise in applying expected values: Let $E[t]$ denote the expected time in hell. Then with probability $1/3$, Amanda reaches heaven (so 0 days), with probability $1/3$ she has to spend $1 + E[t]$ days in hell (why?), and with probability $1/3$, $2 + E[t]$ days, so $E[t] = 1/3 * 0 + 1/3 * (1+E[t]) + 1/3 * (2+E[t])$. Does this help? I'll gladly expand this into an answer, but I don't know where you're stuck.

Comment: @JohannesKloos I am sorry but why 1/3 * 0 ? why not 1/3*(0 + E[t]) ?

Comment: Informally, this shouldn’t be “surprising”, because we would expect in some sense (on average) each door be entered one time each, which gives 3 days in hell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the average time to reach heaven be $t$ days. The probability of choosing each door is 1/3. If she chooses the second door, she spends 1 day in hell, after which on average she would again need on average $t$ days to reach heaven. Similarly for the third door. Thus, we can write an equation
$$
t=\frac{1}{3}(t+1) + \frac{1}{3}(t+2)
$$
and find $t=3$.